# How to set DESTDIR for gmake in rpmbuild SPEC file

Tags: gnu-make, qmake, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build a SPEC file to support a customized RPM for Qt. Because Qt's configure script doesn't recognize some of the options automatically included in the %configure scriptlet I have to call it explicitly in the SPEC file with
`./configure --prefix=%{_qtdir} -confirm-license -opensource -system-sqlite -opengl desktop` where _qtdir is /opt/custom/SENSOR.

My problem is that the %install step fails by trying to install directly to /opt/custom/SENSOR instead of under the BUILDROOT directory. I've tried setting DESTDIR and prefix with no luck, e.g.

```
%install
make install prefix=%{_buildrootdir}/%{sensor}.Qt-%{version}-1.el7_9.x86_64%{_qtdir}
```

How do I get `make install` to respect an installation directory other than what was given to the configure script?

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to work like

```
make install DESTDIR=%{_buildrootdir}
```

Distributions may have some macros defined to help you there, e.g. on Fedora

```
%build
%configure
%make_build

%install
%make_install
```